# Google sheets: Query function produces many values in first row - what is going wrong

Tags: google-sheets

My Google Sheets function returns a lot of values in the first row before putting values in the next ones. I don't understand what could be going wrong. Any tips?

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY('All orders DE'!A2:KL200,"SELECT D"))
```

[image: image of output]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY('All orders DE'!A2:KL200, "SELECT D", 0))
```

Comment: Hi @player0, do you know why that happend, the defult header should be 0 right?

Comment: @Osm this happens with larger datasets whenever 3rd query parameter is not defined. query is a buggy function and it likes to assume stuff that breaks the output